# Navigation Drawer change fragment programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm writing an `Android` app using the `Navigation Drawer`. I want to change the current `fragment` upon a button is clicked.

```
public void btnClick(){
    ...
    changeFragment();
    ...
}

private void changeFragment() {
    Fragment home = new Home();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.navigation_drawer, home);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I'm receiving the following error in `LogCat`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsupportedOpetaionException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

My `Home` fragment is loaded and displayed at the beginning, and after moving to another fragment and clicking a button I want to automatically return to the `Home` fragment.

How can I manage to do it?

EDIT: Full error log

```
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023): Process: com.susu.appclient, PID: 5023
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:968)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-28 21:19:26.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Where is the code where you have used `addView(View)`.

Comment: That's all the code for changing the fragment. With `changeFragment()` as a comment the app runs fluently. But as I want to change the fragment, I'm using the code written above and my app crashed with the error I have mentioned in the full `LogCat` that I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand, you are trying to change the fragment below the navigation drawer, and not the navigation drawer itself (which is a lot more complex).

In this line:

```
 ft.replace(R.id.navigation_drawer, home);
```

You must replace R.id.navigation_drawer for a FragmentLayout that should be on your activitylayout.xml.

Something like:

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, home);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Needed to put the `container` id instead. Thanks!